# Two scrollbars for one div or table in CSS

Tags: html, css

How can we add an additional horizontal scroll bar to an existing table or div which already have a horizontal scroll bar and have them working in sync?

Comment: can you explain why you want to add two horizontal bars if that you have already one?

Comment: you are right, but when you have a big table and you need to enable the user to scroll wherever he/she is.

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily done by this.

```js
$(function(){
    $(".wmd-view-topscroll").scroll(function(){
        $(".wmd-view")
            .scrollLeft($(".wmd-view-topscroll").scrollLeft());
    });
    $(".wmd-view").scroll(function(){
        $(".wmd-view-topscroll")
            .scrollLeft($(".wmd-view").scrollLeft());
    });
});
```

```css
.wmd-view-topscroll, .wmd-view {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    width: 300px;
    border: none 0px RED;
}

.wmd-view-topscroll { height: 20px; }
.wmd-view { height: 200px; }
.scroll-div1 { 
    width: 1000px; 
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.scroll-div2 { 
    width: 1000px; 
    height:20px;
}
`
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wmd-view-topscroll">
    <div class="scroll-div1">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wmd-view">
    <div class="scroll-div2">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sit amet ultricies ex, sit amet pretium ipsum. Duis orci arcu, euismod et leo tincidunt, pharetra molestie tellus. Morbi accumsan convallis massa, quis finibus libero rhoncus at. Nunc porta nisl vel lectus feugiat tincidunt. Aliquam mollis nibh sed nibh varius dapibus. Nullam varius, magna aliquet pellentesque egestas, quam felis malesuada felis, vel dictum nibh massa sit amet eros. Sed eu mauris ut libero luctus semper ac eu turpis. Mauris non pulvinar eros. Suspendisse suscipit tristique risus et dictum. Proin nec mi sit amet massa placerat dictum. Pellentesque cursus, magna a vestibulum finibus, arcu arcu viverra nunc, sed pharetra magna libero non nulla.

Vestibulum non odio tristique nisl venenatis commodo. Sed elementum quam vel metus condimentum, non blandit sapien tempus. Suspendisse mollis velit vel risus hendrerit fermentum. In nec sodales lectus. Integer pharetra bibendum justo vel fermentum. Praesent mollis, turpis ac semper eleifend, diam metus eleifend arcu, nec dictum nulla erat ut sem. Integer urna nisl, venenatis in malesuada id, tincidunt eu dui. Nulla eget bibendum purus. Phasellus ac consectetur arcu, nec aliquam eros. Nullam laoreet tempor lectus, tincidunt maximus ligula ullamcorper euismod.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is a very good solution, unfortunately we have to us JS some how.. I had hope that we can make this without an additional library but no problem. Thanks =D

Comment: Anything you can do in jQuery, you can also do in JavaScript. After all, jQuery does it in JavaScript right?

Comment: Yes indeed you can do it in javascript but JQUERY'S approach is more convenient , more fast and easy to use.Let me know if you want to know how to done that.

Comment: @AhmedsaysReinstateMonica You tagged the wrong guy bud

Comment: @Louay Alosh, consider a green tick to sure that my answer helped you with that this will be correct answer to people having same problem

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it right, you might want to try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".wmd-view-topscroll").scroll(function() {
    $(".wmd-view")
      .scrollLeft($(".wmd-view-topscroll").scrollLeft());
  });
  $(".wmd-view").scroll(function() {
    $(".wmd-view-topscroll")
      .scrollLeft($(".wmd-view").scrollLeft());
  });
});
```

```css
.wmd-view-topscroll,
.wmd-view {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  border: none 0px RED;
}

.wmd-view-topscroll {
  height: 20px;
}

.wmd-view {
  height: 150px;
}

.scroll-div1 {
  width: 1000px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 20px;
}

.scroll-div2 {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wmd-view-topscroll">
  <div class="scroll-div1">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wmd-view">
  <div class="scroll-div2">
    content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
    content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
  </div>
</div>
```

[Source](https://jsfiddle.net/dagope/DtRTq/)